# Link the value of one field to other

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I want to be able to change the value of input B, if input A is changed, but if input B is changed I want input A to stay the same as it was. How can i do this? Here is an example code (which is not working):

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="pages" aria-describedby="pagesHelp" placeholder="pages" v-model="pages">
<input type="number" v-model="bwpages" class="form-control totalPages" placeholder="black and white pages" value="{{ pages }}">
```

If I change the field `pages` I want to value for `bwpages` to change as well, but if I change `bwpages` I don't want `pages` to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use watcher instead.`<input type="number" class="form-control" id="pages" aria-describedby="pagesHelp" placeholder="pages" v-model="pages">
<input type="number" v-model="bwpages" class="form-control totalPages" id="bwbpages" placeholder="black and white pages">`

removing the value binding. and watching for change of a and updating the b. but doing nothing when b changes.

```
watch: {
 pages(newval, oldval) {
   this.bwpages = newval
 }
}
```

Comment: the code that worked for me was this one `watch: {
  pages(val) {
   this.bwpages = val;
  }
 }`

Comment: you can edit the answer and i will mark it as solved